# Select all elements of a vector except one in dplyr pipeline

Tags: r, vector, dplyr

I want to select all the elements of a character vector except one that matches a specific character.
I could do it easily with `%in%`, but I don't see how to do this inside a `dplyr` pipeline.

Example:
What I want

```
names<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
names[!names %in% "c"]
 [1] "a" "b" "d" "e"
```

How I want it:

```
names<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
names %>% ...something...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If there are no duplicates, we can use `setdiff`

```
library(magrittr)
names %>% 
     setdiff(., "c")
#[1] "a" "b" "d" "e"
```

---

Or use the magrittr operations to subset the vector.

```
names %>%
   `%in%`("c") %>% 
   `!` %>%
    extract(names, .)
#[1] "a" "b" "d" "e"
```

Comment: This will be different from the expected result in case there are any duplicates in the vector

Comment: @docendodiscimus  `names1 <- c(names, "c");
identical(names1 %>%  setdiff(., "c"), names1[!names1 %in% "c"])
#[1] TRUE`

Comment: try this instead: `names1 <- c(names, "a"); identical(names1 %>% setdiff(., "c"), names1[!names1 %in% "c"]) #[1] FALSE`

Comment: This is standard for set operations

Comment: The second option seems to be correct. I just hope nobody is actually going to use it seriously, to be honest (no offense meant).

Comment: @docendodiscimus  I guess this is for educational purpose and in cases where the OP doesn't want to break off from the chain and do this separately.

Comment: The first solution did the trick for me, as I don't have any duplicates in my character vector. And yes, I didn't want to do this outside the chain. Thanks!

Comment: Possible. I personally would strongly advise to break any chain instead. I think it's the exact opposite of the pipe's intention (which is to make code more readable)